# Desplegar una app de laravel en Debian

Tags: php, laravel, linux, debian

tengo un proyecto de back end hecho en laravel el cal en mi computadora de desarrollo funciona bien, al ingresar a la carpeta publica del sitio web me muestra esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero publicar la aplicacion en un servidor debian11.
Tengo instalado apache, php 7.4, composer.

Al copiar el proyecto a centos, ejcuto el comando php artisan route:clear, y php artisan optimize
Se ejcutan correctamente pero al querer ver la carpeta public del proyecto en el servidor debian me muestra asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y claro no esta funcionando, alguien que me pueda guiar por donde esta el error?

Comment: Que servidor HTTP usas?

Comment: Agrega la configuración del apache.

Comment: @fredyfx igual usa un nginx.. por eso preguntaba xD

Comment: @adrigo ¿Seguro? porque en la pregunta dice `Tengo instalado apache`.

Comment: @fredyfx perdón, se ve que mi cerebro omitió esa parte... Error mio, disculpa.

Comment: Normal bro, todo fresh~